# TexStudio cannot compile presentation

Tags: errors, windows, texstudio, presentations

I have been using TexStudio for a long time with no problem in creating pdf files. But now I have to make a presentation with LaTeX and it does not compile.

I tried every tutorial that appears when you search "latex presentation"

Most of them use the beamer package. When I open the .tex file and Press F1, the cursor starts spinning and nothing happens.

Two files appear: `filename.gz(busy)` and `filename.log` the `.gz` file is empty, the log file contains this :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.3.6)  27 MAR 2014 20:50
entering extended mode
**testbmr.tex
(C:\Users\asdf\Downloads\testbmr.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamer.cls"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasercs.sty"
Package: beamerbasercs 2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
)
Document Class: beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (r
cs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasemodes.sty"
Package: beamerbasemodes 2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count79
\c@beamerpauses=\count80

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbasedecode.sty"
Package: beamerbasedecode 2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
\beamer@slideinframe=\count81
\beamer@minimum=\count82
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box27
\beamer@modecount=\count83
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
\headheight=\dimen102
\headdp=\dimen103
\footheight=\dimen104
\sidebarheight=\dimen105
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen106
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen107
\beamer@animht=\dimen108
\beamer@animdp=\dimen109
\beamer@animwd=\dimen110
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen112
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen114
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen115
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen116
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen117
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen118
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box28
\beamer@animcurrent=\box29
\beamer@animshowbox=\box30
\beamer@sectionbox=\box31
\beamer@logobox=\box32
\beamer@linebox=\box33
\beamer@sectioncount=\count84
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count85
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count86
\beamer@sectionmax=\count87
\beamer@totalheads=\count88
\beamer@headcounter=\count89
\beamer@partstartpage=\count90
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count91
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count92
\beamer@animationtempa=\count93
\beamer@animationtempb=\count94
\beamer@xpos=\count95
\beamer@ypos=\count96
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count97
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count98
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count99
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count100
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count101

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\beamerbaseoptions.sty
"
Package: beamerbaseoptions 2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count102
\Gm@cntv=\count103
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count104
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen119
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen123
\Gm@layoutheight=\dim
```

I need to start writing my presentation urgently, and I cannot do anything except banging my head into walls..

Any reccomendations? Another IDE? Another packet manager?

Thanks for any help..

### System Specs

Windows 7 64 bit

TexStudio 2.7.0

MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: Other than banging your head walls, you can show us the code you are trying to compile. Before that, you can try to compile a very simple document, something like `\documentclass{beamer} \begin{document} \begin{frame} Hello, world! \end{frame} \end{document}` to start building confidence and the process of finding where the error is.

Comment: My guess: some package is missing and it fails to automatically download and install. Try to start Texstudio as admin and recompile.

Comment: @remus I tried running it as admin. djas, it happens in every single tutorial on the web. I will try the simple code now. Thanks ! **edit** It works. So it is some package, but I don't know which one. How can I find out ?

Comment: Best way is to install a complete (full) miktex.

Comment: When you installed miktex, did you choose to automatically install missing packages, to notify you about them or to not take any action? If you chose to install them one way or another then maybe the default repository server is down. You can change it from Package Manager (type it in Start->Run).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.